# How to read php.ini values at runtime?

Tags: php, ini

I am writing a PHP library and to increase its portability and robustness I would like to be able to read the php.ini file to access the installation settings.

Is there a simple way to do this or do I need to do this the hard way and write code to parse this myself?

Thanks

Answer (score 9):

I doubt that you need **all** of the php.ini file. For specific values, why not use [`ini_get()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-get.php)? For example, to get the maximum post size, you can simply use:

```
$maxPostSize = ini_get('post_max_size');
```

Comment: +1 even if all values in `php.ini` are needed, [`ini_get_all`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ini-get-all.php) can be used instead of (and is more detailed than) using `parse_ini_file` to parse the `php.ini`. So I believe this is the best answer.

Answer (score 6):

PHP has a nice support for INI files. Along with the `php_ini_loaded_file()` you can get the details of current ini file.

```
<?php 

    // get path to the ini file
    $inipath = php_ini_loaded_file();

    // Parse with sections
    $ini_array = parse_ini_file($inipath , true);
    print_r($ini_array);

?>
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.php-ini-loaded-file.php